# Animate highlight color on hover with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On [Brackets.io](http://brackets.io) I noticed that when I highlighted their logo and hovered over it changed the highlight color which is something I have never seen before. Also, if you look closely you'll also notice that their icon changes color at the same time. Is this something you can do with Javascript and jQuery? Or could this be done through [CSS by itself](https://css-tricks.com/overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/)?

Would it be something like...

```
$('#logo').hover(function(){
  $(this).animate({ highlight: green }, 'slow');
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reassembled a snippet of their HTML and CSS below:

```css
.brackets-logo a {
    color: #000;
    font: 400 19px / 50px source-sans-pro, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.brackets-logo i {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0 7px 0 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    background: url(http://brackets.io/img/sprite.svg) no-repeat 0 0;
    background-size: 18px 94px;
}

.brackets-logo:hover {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
    filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 3s;
    -moz-transition: all 3s;
    transition: all 3s;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="brackets-logo"><a href="#">
<i></i>Brackets</a></h1>
```

Looks like they're using [the CSS `filter` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) and `transition`.  `filter` has [some decent support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters) using prefixes (sans IE).

**Alternative**

You could also combine the CSS `animate` property and the `:hover` pseudo-class and `::selection` pseudo-element to animate the text selection color.  You would have to use an inline `svg` for the little bracket icon though, so you could animate it's `fill` property as well.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved using css filters.
Specifically the one you have mentioned is hue-rotate filter. 
Check out this [demo](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/filters/index.html).

You can write css as

```
myelement:hover{

    filter: hue-rotate(360deg);

}
```

or to be safe with different browsers

```
myelement:hover{

     -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
    filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 3s;
    -moz-transition: all 3s;
    transition: all 3s;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [CSS Transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp).

```
.logo {
  color:grey;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s; /* Safari */
    transition: all 1s;
}

.logo:hover {
  color:red;
}
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dkf6mued/)

Comment: Wouldn't that just change the font color?

Comment: yes, this works if you use an icon as logo. If you want to use a image, just  made a white PNG with transparent pixel to draw your logo. Then change background-color with CSS and transition

Comment: The logo is actually just text and the effect only happens when it's highlighted. It's not just a simple background color transition.

Comment: See [CSS ::selection selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_selection.asp)